# How to reliably use a matrix (multivariable) response in R using a formula?

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, multivalue

I am trying to use a multivariable response in `R` and came across the damned formulas, and having all sorts of unexpected behaviors, mainly when using them inside functions and packages. This question is twofold

> I can input a multivariable response and be able to use the model to predict afterwards?

This MVE, using `rpart` package, serves as an example. Here `y` is a two-column matrix (response), and I want to predict `y` using `x`, i.e. each column in `x` (two columns in this MVE). Note that the `method` itself and what each column in `y` mean is irrelevant, this is just a MVE to reproduce the problem:

```
library(rpart)

set.seed(1)
y <- rpois(10, lambda = 1.25)
y <- cbind(c(1,4,10,11,12, 14,16,17,20, 21), y)
print(y)
x <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 2) # just two dummy predictors
print(x)

mymodel <- rpart(y ~ x, method = "poisson", minbucket = 1)

newx <- matrix(11:20, ncol = 2) # just some dummy test predictors, note that we have less rows
predict(mymodel, newdata = data.frame(newx))
# output:
        1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          
 9         10 
 0.12500000 0.12500000 0.12500000 0.20000000 0.04761905 0.17948718 0.17948718 0.11538462 
 0.04000000 0.04000000 
 Warning message:
 'newdata' had 5 rows but variables found have 10 rows
```

As you can see, I can't predict a new dataset. I have been messing with the column and row names and have not been able to make it work.

In addition,

> How can I make a wrapper that is "safe"?

For example, in this MVE:

```
mywrapper <- function(y, x){
  mymodel <- rpart(y ~ x, method = "poisson", minbucket = 1)
  
  return(mymodel)
}
```

and provided the help provided in the R documentation:

> A formula object has an associated environment, and this environment (rather than the parent environment) is used by model.frame to evaluate variables that are not found in the supplied data argument.
> Formulas created with the ~ operator use the environment in which they were created. Formulas created with as.formula will use the env argument for their environment.

I don't really understand what this is supposed to mean. As far as I understand it, not inputing nor `y` or `x` to `mywrapper()` will result in an error (this is the expected behavior). I ask because I am dealing with r packages and functions inside packages and I want to make sure that there is no unexpected behavior with the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking formulas in R work well with dataframes.  `rpart` works on matrices, and while dataframes can hold matrices, they tend to get converted to separate columns.  To avoid this, wrap the matrix in `I()`:

```r
# Same as your code to start...then this:

predict(mymodel, newdata = data.frame(x = I(newx)))
#>    1    2    3    4    5 
#> 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04
```

In the second part of your question, you are creating a formula in the `mywrapper` function, so that's where it will look for variables if they aren't contained in the `newdata` dataframe.  "Environments" in R are similar to "stack frames" in other languages; the main difference is that environments have a single parent and searches proceed there if the object isn't found in the original.

Generally speaking the parent is *not* the frame of the caller, it is the frame where the environment was created, or something specially listed as the parent.

So what happens if you run `predict` on the returned value from `mywrapper` is that it looks at the formula to find what variables it needs.  Only the variables on the right hand side are needed for predictions, so that's just `x`.  If you supply `x` in your `newdata` argument to `predict`, everything will be fine and proceed as before, but if you don't, things are different.

Since `x` was not found in the `newdata`, it goes to the environment of the formula.  That's the evaluation frame of `mywrapper`, and it will see `x` there, since it was an argument to that function.

If it was looking for `z` instead, it wouldn't find it there.  The next place to look is the parent environment, which is the one in effect when `mywrapper` was created, i.e. the global environment.  If there's no `z` there, it would search through the chain of environments listed by `search()`, which are typically package exports.  The `search()` list is chained together so that each entry is the parent of the one before.

I hope this isn't too much information....

Comment: That worked! and definitely not too much information, it's very much appreciated. I'm still worried about those "Generally speaking", though

Comment: The exceptions to formulas working well in dataframes are usually programmer error.  Since package authors aren't always experts, sometimes they get it wrong.  The authors of rpart know what they're doing, so that's not a problem here.  The exceptions to "parent != caller" are usually cases where the parent is explicitly set to be the caller, but it also happens with nested functions:  f creates g locally then calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with `rpart:predict`, but for this function you need a new dataset that has the same variables as the original one, according to the documentation.

So, you should initiate newx with the correct column names:

```
newx = matrix(11:20, ncol = 2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("x1","x2")))
```

Now, the columns are labeled `x1` and `x2`, just as the variables in your model and predict will know what to do with these columns.

Comment: How do you input this to `predict()`? Using `data.frame(newx)` does not work.

Comment: Using  ` newx <- matrix(11:20, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x","y")))` and then 
`predict(mymodel, newdata = as.data.frame(newx))` throws the error *Error: variable 'x' was fitted with type "nmatrix.2" but type "numeric" was supplied*. Using `newx <- matrix(11:20, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1","x2")))` gives the same error as before.

Comment: Ah, right. You train the model to predict a matrix given another matrix. You can't put that in a data frame. As said above, I don't use the rpart library, myself. I don't know how to predict in this case.